# How to divide a number by 10 only in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, operators

I just need to divide some number by only 10. For instance, if the number is 127, the result should only be 12 and remained to be 7. Is there a way I can get Python to give me these BOTH results?  Because I need to divide that remainder by some number as well for instance 2.
So overall it should be like this:
127 = 12 (10) and 3 (2) and 1(remainder).

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 4):

You can try using double division and modulus division -

```
quotient = 127 // 10

remainder = 127 % 10


print(quotient) # 12
print(remainder) # 7
```

Or use `divmod` -

```
num = 127
d = 10 # Divisor

quotient,remainder = divmod(num, d) # It returns tuple 

print(quotient) # 12
print(remainder) # 7
```

Comment: There's also a `divmod` builtin to do both. It's mostly useful for cases where the operation is expensive, such as with integers thousands of digits long.

Answer (score 1):

```
def divide_and_get_remainder(num, divisor):
    quotient = num // divisor
    remainder = num % divisor
    return quotient, remainder

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = 127
    divisor = 10
    q, r = divide_and_get_remainder(num,divisor)
    print(f'{num} / {divisor} = {q} with remainder = {r}')
```